# Getting the name of the workbook that a macro belongs to

Tags: excel, vba

I've looked around and can't find an answer to this question.

So I have a workbook who's name could be changed (as it's being used by a sales team) and it has a macro that is triggered when a new workbook is opened to pull data out of that new workbook. Since the focus at this point is on the new workbook, I'd like to set the active sheet back to the first workbook. I'm hoping there's a property that lets a macro call its parent's name? I close the newly opened workbook once I've pulled the data from it, but they may have other workbooks open on their computers and so the focus could switch to them when the data workbook closes.

Thanks for the info!

EDIT: So to clarify, macro runs as workbook focus is lost, would like to switch focus back to workbook that the macro belongs to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after fiddling a little longer in the Macro it appears that `Me.Name` returns the name of the workbook the macro belongs to! The code `Application.Workbooks(Me.Name).Activate` did what I wanted. Hopefully this'll help someone else.

Answer (score 3):

'Application.Workbooks(Me.Name)' does not seem to work with MS Office 2016.
However, 'Application.ThisWorkbook' does.

ThisWorkbook refers to where macro belongs to.
ActiveWorkbook refers to where focus is.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Dim sName as String
sName = ThisWorkbook.Name
```

Comment: This seems to return the name of the currently active workbook, which in this case is the newly opened data file rather than the parent of the macro. `Application.Workbooks(Me.Name).Activate` seems to have worked for me, but thanks for taking the time to answer :)